# Learning Links and Linked Data Structures Java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, linked-list

I am learning Linked Data Structures and the concept makes sense to me, however the code does not.

I was hoping someone could explain this for me.

This is from lecture slides:

I have a constructor here:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    private E value;
    private Node<E> next;
    private Node( E value, Node<E> next ) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Value- stores actual information. 
Next- stores reference to the previous object stored. Makes sense.

But then...

```
public void addFirst( E o ) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>( o, null );
    if ( head == null ) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
}
```

The above code is supposed to be adding elements.
But here is my problem: `newNode` created. `newNode.next` field stores the reference to object head. (by the way, I have no idea where head is declared) **and then**: `head=newNode`.

So Head now has the value that was stored by `newNode`, and `head.next` is now referencing itself?

The problem here is that the original value in head is lost, and there is no reference to `newNode`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You aren't showing all the code. Clearly `head` must be declared somewhere, probably in a `LinkedList` class?

Comment: If you are adding to the beginning of a singly linked list, the new head should be the new node. The old head should be in head.next. That code can definitely be simplified.

Comment: "head.next = newNode" will make more sense to me.

Comment: head.next makes more sense to me to. But the above code is from lecture slides. so there should not be anything wrong with it.

Comment: It's obvious that head is declared somewhere in class, that contains method addFirst

Comment: If you do head.next = newNode, it's not a addFirst adding, it's something like addSecond

Comment: Obviously head is declared somewhere, but its irrelevant. Head has properties of Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the objects' identities. Consider the following classes with their fields:

```
List<E>
    Node<E> head
Node<E>
    E value
    Node<E> next
```

Let's say you have an Empty List, which means there are these objects (actually just one):

```
List(1)
    head = null
```

To better illustrate, I gave the object a unique number. In reality, an object is identified unambiguously by its memory location.

Now add `"as"` to the list:

`Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>( o, null );`

```
List(1)
    head = null
Node(2)
    value = "as"
    next = null
```

`head = newNode;`

```
List(1)
    head = Node(2)
Node(2)
    value = "as"
    next = null
```

and now add `"df"`:

`Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>( o, null );`

```
List(1)
    head = Node(2)
Node(2)
    value = "as"
    next = null
Node(3)
    value = "df"
    next = null
```

`newNode.next = head;`

```
List(1)
    head = Node(2)
Node(2)
    value = "as"
    next = null
Node(3)
    value = "df"
    next = Node(2)
```

`head = newNode;`

```
List(1)
    head = Node(3)
Node(2)
    value = "as"
    next = null
Node(3)
    value = "df"
    next = Node(2)
```

As you can see, the single node's values were not changed, and the new `head`, `Node(3)` does not reference itself. `head` has value `"df"`, the next node has `"as"`, so `"df"` was indeed added in front of the existing node.

---

As others have also noted, `addFirst` could be greatly simplified. Look at the original:

```
Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>( o, null );
if ( head == null ) {
    head = newNode;
} else {
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
}
```

The `head = newNode;` line appears at the bottom of both of the `if`'s branches, so it can be moved out:

```
Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>( o, null );
if ( head == null ) {
} else {
    newNode.next = head;
}
head = newNode;
```

...which leaves the `then` branch empty, so better reverse the condition:

```
Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>( o, null );
if ( head != null ) {
    newNode.next = head;
}
head = newNode;
```

Looking closely, after that `if`, `newNode.next` will be the (old) `head` regardless of whether the `if` was executed (then it's obvious) or not (the constructor set it to null, and if the `if` isn't executed, then `head` was `null` too). So another way to write this would be:

```
Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>( o, head );
head = newNode;
```

And now you have a variable that's only used once:

```
head = new Node<E>( o, head );
```

But really, write the code the way you can understand it better, especially if your objective is learning.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify addFirst to this:

```
public void addFirst( E o ) {
    head = new Node<E>( o, head );
}
```

head will be set to the new node. The old head will be in `head.next`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you miss that method is called addFirst, so it's the method for adding element **before** head. That's exactly what method is really doing. It creating a new node, set it's next on head, and then update's head of the list, pointing to a newly created node.

Since java is pass-by-value this code should work correctly.

Comment: After head=newNode call, would head's value not be erased?

Comment: java pass everything by value, so the answer is no

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there is definitely something missing from the example.  Either the author made a mistake, or wants you to think through the problem and fill in the blanks.  Based on the addFirst method you quoted, "head" would need to be defined in the class that defines the addFirst method.  But the Node class example does essentially the same thing with its constructor.  The class constructor is adding the new Node to the front of the list (which is exactly what addFirst does).  Assuming there are isn't any other data, addFirst() doesn't make any sense in context with Node as defined.  Since all of the definitions in Node are private, there has to be a containing object that would use it (Node is probably a nested class).

So maybe something like this:

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    private class Node<E> {
        private E value;
        private Node<E> next;
        private Node( E value, Node<E> next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private Node<E> head;

    //Create a linked list
    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
    }

    //Add a node to the front of the list
    public void addFirst( E o ) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>( o, head);
        head = newNode;
    }
}
```

Using it would look something like:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.addFirst("A");
list.addFirst("B");
list.addFirst("C");
```

would end up with something like "C" -> "B" -> "A" in the list.